# How to change the color Ok and Cancel button in custompicker(drop down) in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Here i try to write the code, Change the color Ok and Cancel button in Picker(DropDown).

```
builder.SetNegativeButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#CE1126'>Back it up</font>"), (s, a) =>
{
   ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);

    Control?.ClearFocus();
    dialog = null;
 });
builder.SetPositiveButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Roger that, 10-4!</font>"), (s, a) =>
{
   ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);

    if (Element != null)
    {
       if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
           Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];

           ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);

           Control?.ClearFocus();
     }
       dialog = null;
  });
```

This is Code , i write the in Custom Render

Comment: Are you try with a customRenderer?

Comment: Yes .. Miguel Angel

Comment: Please solve this problem,  as soon as possible

Comment: Hi.. Please tell the solution

Comment: Please, tell me some solution .. please